# Is there any info on whether nested Document Sets will ever be supported?

Tags: office-365, document-set, 2016

Document sets are a very elegant way of treating as a single unit many related documents and other content items - just about everything except for other Document Sets.

A few competing products have had similar objects (one of them uses the term "Compound Document") for quite a while, ones that even allow nesting.

Has anyone here heard one way or another whether SharePoint will support nested Document Sets, either sooner or later?

Thanks in advance,
Josh

Comment: No idea but a hack to allow nested documents (at least in 2013) is to create a folder then have a workflow run and change the folder to a document set. The result allows the folder to have meta data but not the welcome page.

Comment: I did see that in a couple of posts. Obviously, though, it's not something an average user can be expected to master. Hmmm ... I wonder if the absence of a welcome page in the nested Document Set is the reason that Microsoft doesn't officially support this. I'd venture a guess that most people could live with nested Document Sets without nested welcome pages ...

Comment: You can set it via a workflow to run on item creation. The end user does not need to do anything. My understand re:welcome page is that the convert from folder to doc set is buggy not that it can't support it

Answer (score 0):

If they are officially supported, is yet to be reviled. But using PowerShell you can create a Document Set in a Document Set without going through the process of first creating a Folder and change the Content Type.

For testing I used this script:

```
# Get the site
$site = Get-SPSite http://portal

# Get the first web (I only have 1)
$web = $site.AllWebs[0]

# Get the list
$list = $web.Lists["Documents"]

# Create an empty variable
$ct = ""

# Iterate the list Content Types, and grab the Document Set Content type Id.
# Assign the Id to your empty variable $ct
foreach($ctype in $list.ContentTypes)
{
    if($ctype.Name -eq "Document Set")
    {
        Write-Host $ctype.Name $ctype.Id -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $ct = $ctype.Id
    }
}

# Get the rootfolder
$rootFolder = $list.RootFolder

# Iterate your Document Sets (and Folders) to get your DocSet
foreach($docsetFolder in $rootFolder.SubFolders)
{
    if($docsetFolder.Name -eq "DocSet")
    {
        Write-Host "Current Document Set:" $docsetFolder.Name
        Write-Host "Its SubFolders      :" $docsetFolder.SubFolders.Name

        # Create the Document Set in the DocSet        
        $NewFolder = [Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSet]::Create($docsetFolder,"DocSet in DocSet",$ct)
    }
}

$site.Dispose()
```

Which outputs

[image]

When I'm done, this is the result in the browser

[image]

And the DocSet in DocSet do have a Welcome Page too

[image]

Comment: is there a powershell script to make it available for end users to create document set inside a document set?